# What are these red link icons?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I have just updated my game and noticed that when I play some of my character skills have red chain icons with letters. I have highlighted them in the image with a pink circle.

What are these icons and what do they mean?

[image: Golden bomb event]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that these are chain family icons. [I found a post on Reddit which has further details](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFBraveExvius/comments/chm7ks/chain_family_showing_on_skills/).

> When you click on a skill with Chain Family on the unit's page, it brings up the descriptions and a "Detail" button, clicking on the button will list out the entire list of skills

[image: List of chain abilities]

[Someone else on Reddit has compiled a list](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFBraveExvius/comments/chm7ks/chain_family_showing_on_skills/euuz2jp/)

- AMoE - Absolute Mirror of Equity
- AR - Aureole Ray
- BS - Bolting Strike
- Dsd - Disorder
- AZ - Absolute Zero
- SR - Stardust Ray
- Frz - Freeze
- TnD - Tornado
- GC - Graviton Cannon (though when you long-press the name is "Short-Range Graviton")
- QH - Quick Hit
- Pd - Piledriver
- DR - Divine Ruination
- OcS - Octaslash
- KG - Kingsglaive
- Fld - Flood
- OnS - Onion Slice
- CW - Chaos Wave

I assume that this will ease players ability to build consistent chains when attacking by matching units which share a chain family.